# Assigning values to an input before it is created

Tags: r, shiny

**Note: the first example below is not particularly clear - I've added another example below which more clearly explains the desired behavior.**

I'm running into a slightly tricky issue with an app that I am building. I am using `uiOutput` to dynamically render a series of `radioButtons`. However, I need to assign values to the inputs *before* they are created. I recognize that this might not make sense, but in my actual use case I see no other way around this.

In the example below, I would like to create three inputs, `input$mpg`, `input$hp` and `input$disp` and assign them each a value of `yes` *before* the UI is generated. Then, when the UI is generated, I would like to replace those default values with the selected value. Note that in the example below, I am including an `actionButton` to prevent those inputs from being immediately created by the UI.

Can anyone suggest an approach for how to accomplish this?

```
library(shiny)

var_names <- c("mpg", "hp", "disp")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go!"),
  uiOutput("var_type")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    output$var_type <- renderUI({
      var_names %>% map(~radioButtons(inputId = .x,
                                      label = .x,
                                      choices = c("Yes", "No")))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit: New Example for Improved Clarity**

I am using `uiOutput` to dynamically render three `radioButtons`. The values of these radioButtons will be concatenated into a string and rendered in the `textOutput` "values". However, these three radioButtons and their associated inputs are only generated after an actionButton, `Go!`, is clicked.

Prior to the actionButton being clicked and the radioButtons and their associated inputs being rendered, I would still like to render the `textOutput`, using a default set of values for these inputs. I would like to assign default values of `yes` to each of the three inputs. This the root cause of my problem as I would like to in-effect create a placeholder input and assign it a value prior to the actual input being following the clicking of the `Go!` button.

Prior to clicking `Go!`, I would like the textOutput `values` to read 'Yes Yes Yes' as these are the default values previously mentioned. However, after `Go!` is clicked and the radioButtons rendered, the `textOutput` "values" should be responsive to these changing inputs. For example, if, after clicking Go, the button for `mpg` was changed to "No", then the text would read `No Yes Yes`.

```
library(shiny)

var_names <- c("mpg", "hp", "disp")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go!"),
  uiOutput("var_type"),
  textOutput("values")
)
  
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    output$var_type <- renderUI({
      var_names %>% map(~radioButtons(inputId = .x,
                                      label = .x,
                                      choices = c("Yes", "No")))
    })
  })
  output$values <- renderText({
    paste(input$mpg, input$hp, input$disp)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: So why aren't you putting them directly into the `fluidPage()`? I don't really understand what behavior you are trying to create here.

Comment: In the actual use case, the variable choices are dependent on an uploaded table, so I can't define them ahead of time in the ui as I don't know what they are until the user uploads something

Comment: Also, I need to use the defaults in other operations on the server side, before the radioButtons are rendered

Comment: One more clarification, I need to use the defaults in another operation before the radioButtons are rendered, but also have that operation be responsive to the UI choices once they are rendered. If that makes any sense

Comment: I'm sorry, this still does not make sense to me. What is the behavior you would like from your reproducible example? What do I need to test in order to verify it works how you like?

Comment: Thank you for bearing with me @MrFlick. I've added a reworded example for better clarity. Fingers crossed it makes more sense now!

Comment: If the first example is not clear and doesn't explain your problem clearly why not remove it completely and keep only the edit part in your post.

Comment: i got yelled at previously for modifying a question too much, so i figured keep the original in there and simply explicitly state that a better alternative has been listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(shiny)

var_names <- c("mpg", "hp", "disp")

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go", "Go!"),
  uiOutput("var_type"),
  textOutput("values")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$go, {
    output$var_type <- renderUI({
      var_names %>% map(~radioButtons(inputId = .x,
                                      label = .x,
                                      choices = c("Yes", "No")))
    })
  })
  output$values <- renderText({
    if (is.null(input$mpg))  val1 = "Yes" else val1 = input$mpg
    if (is.null(input$hp))   val2 = "Yes" else val2 = input$hp
    if (is.null(input$disp)) val3 = "Yes" else val3 = input$disp
    paste(val1, val2, val3)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The actual use case is more complicated than simply subbing in those values. appreciate it though!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `if (input$go <1) paste("Yes","Yes","Yes")
    else paste(input$mpg, input$hp, input$disp)`.  Without further details, I am not sure we can suggest better solution to your use case.